# Having trouble with my raw folder not showing up in code always giving red even though its inside

Tags: android, directory, media-player

[Here is my res folder with the raw folder inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np03s.png)

here is my code however the raw is always red and i cant seem to figure this out any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ourSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Gravity);
```

Comment: have you try restarting Android Studio ?

Comment: oh yea it works i thought i restarted it back then and it didnt work thanks !

Answer (score 0):

change (Gravity.mp3) to (gravity.mp3) .
raw files must be LowerCase, even if this can't solve current problem